# SNMP OID mappings

Tags: networking, monitoring, snmp, pfsense

I am trying to get ifDescr and ifHCInOctets OID from my pfsense firewall. When I issue a Get from snmpwalk:

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c xxxxx 10.1.0.41 .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2
```

I receive the following output:

```
IF-MIB::ifDescr.1 = STRING: igb0
IF-MIB::ifDescr.2 = STRING: igb1
IF-MIB::ifDescr.3 = STRING: igb2
IF-MIB::ifDescr.4 = STRING: igb3
IF-MIB::ifDescr.5 = STRING: igb4
IF-MIB::ifDescr.6 = STRING: igb5
IF-MIB::ifDescr.7 = STRING: bge0
IF-MIB::ifDescr.8 = STRING: bge1
IF-MIB::ifDescr.9 = STRING: pflog0
IF-MIB::ifDescr.10 = STRING: pfsync0
IF-MIB::ifDescr.11 = STRING: lo0
IF-MIB::ifDescr.12 = STRING: enc0
```

When I then try to get the actual counter using:

```
snmpwalk -v 2c -c HornbillRO 10.1.0.41 .1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.6
```

I get the following output:

```
IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets.4 = Counter64: 211912249829
IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets.5 = Counter64: 3483877790783
IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets.6 = Counter64: 7471352835667
```

My first question is, why do I not see all 1-12 interfaces showing when I issue for ifHCInOctets? I only get 4-6 as seen above.

The second question is, can I assume IF-MIB::ifHCInOctets.4 string result is the same interface as shown in IF-MIB::ifDescr.4. I.e. is the 4 unique for this interface, so any other OID requests with .4 (in IF-MIB), will be the data for the 4th interface on my system?

Comment: perhaps other interfaces' counters have not overflowed Counter32 yet and are available under .1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10?

Comment: The index numbering should be consistent, yes.